# Zoom in/out via external keyboard

Tags: zooming, external-keyboard

In there a way to get the effect of (zoom out/pinch put)/in with external mouse and or/keyboard?
For games like angry birds or using google earth.

Answer (score 3):

Hold the key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and  <kbd>↓</kbd>  on your keyboard. Two little opaque circles will appear near your mouse. Hold down the left button of your mouse  and move those little circles. It will zoom in-and-out just using two fingers.

Comment: This works with Andy by the way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an external mouse with a scroll wheel, try rolling the wheel while holding down Ctrl on the keyboard.

This works on countless office-type apps (Word, Excel, Outlook, web browsers, image editors etc). Might work on some games and the like?

Answer (score 1):

I know that in the browser you could do:

```
CTRL+I = Zoom-in on page.
CTRL+O = zoom-out on page.
```

I wonder if this works in some other applications. Have you tried the `+` and `-` keys? How about `CTRL++` or `CTRL+-`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is for Google Maps:
Double click mouse and hold the button down on second click, now to zoom in move cursor up, zoom out move cursor down. After zooming is done release the button. Same thing works in phones and tabs with your finger.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry.

The only way to use pinch zoom is to pinch zoom - using multitouch.

Comment: There is no way just for zoom event on specific point of something? no pinching.
Maybe edit the Generic.kcm?

Comment: http://source.android.com/tech/input/keyboard-devices.html 
I can see in the table that there is a "AC Zoom In/out".
Do you think it possible to map a regular button for that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out in settings that your can find in settings there is an enable button for zoomin and out. Is directly the DISPLAY settings.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the control key down on the external keyboard, then use the + and - signs (near the backspace key) to zoom in and zoom out respectively.